# Disable lap mode on Lenovo laptop

Tags: power-management, lenovo, laptop, 21.10

**My setup :** Lenovo Thinkpad P14s, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz

**Software :** Ubuntu 21.10, Gnome 40.4.0, Linux 5.13.0

**Background :**

Lenovo has a "Lenovo Intelligent Thermal Solution" which is hardwired to some movement sensors that detect when the laptop has been moved and switches to "lap mode" so it throttles the laptop in order to not get hot on the bottom for safe use on your lap.
For months, this created problems on Linux where this feature was not supported, so the laptop was always stuck on lap mode, and performance was always throttled.
This has been fixed since mid-2020, details about this can be found in this document : https://web.archive.org/web/20190926163900if_/https://forums.lenovo.com/lnv/attachments/lnv/Special_Interest_Linux/13642/1/Linux%20Thermal%20throttling.pdf

**I now experience the following problem :**

When moving the laptop, "lap mode" is triggered, so the "performance" power mode in disabled, and it is automatically set to "balanced power". After approximately 5 minutes, "lap mode" turns off, and I can turn the power mode back to "performance", but it is a manual action.

**I have found 2 workarounds for this problem :**

- I can run this script in a crontab every minute, to automatically turn power mode to "performance" as soon as possible :

`p=$(powerprofilesctl) ; if echo "$p" | grep -qF "* balanced" && ! echo "$p" | grep -qF "Inhibited:  yes" ; then powerprofilesctl set performance ; fi`

- I can disable CPU thermal throttling altogether, but this is a "nuclear option", as described in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Extreme#Disabling_BDPROCHOT_to_prevent_throttling_on_battery

**So I'm wondering, is there a way to keep thermal throttling enabled, but disable only lap mode detection ?
Of course, this "lap mode" is detected as soon as I move the laptop to go to another room, but I never use it on my lap...**

PS.

Here is the `powerprofilesctl` command output when "lap mode" is detected.
Gnome setting's "power" page gives similar information.

```
$ powerprofilesctl
  performance:
    Driver:     platform_profile
    Inhibited:  yes (lap-detected)

* balanced:
    Driver:     platform_profile

  power-saver:
    Driver:     platform_profile
```

Comment: Related info for people who might find this report : my Ubuntu 23.04 setup now automatically sets performance mode back on after the firmware stops reporting laptop mode, which is around 5 minutes after last moving the laptop. I'm not sure if this feature comes from the desktop environment or from the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue on my Thinkpad T590! It's caused by a little accelerometer, designed to disable performance mode when the laptop isn't flat & steady.

After spending a few hours trying to figure out the solution, the best way to fix it is to just modify the kernel to always report that the sensor is negative. It's a very simple fix, you only need to change one line in the [thinkpad_acpi](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a175eca0f3d747599f1fdfac04cc9195b71ec996/drivers/platform/x86/thinkpad_acpi.c#L10136) module.

[I've written a patcher to do this automatically using dkms](https://github.com/JosiahBull/thinkpad_acpi), so it'll persist as you update your kernel.

If you're against patching the kernel module, you might be able to ["monkey patch"](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-monkey-patch-the-linux-kernel/) the kernel which is a lot less invasive. There are some details on that in the previously linked repo too.

Comment: This patcher does not seem to work anymore on Ubuntu 23.04/23.10: the patcher hides the warning, powerprofilesctl shows "degraded: No", but CPU still is down to 400Mhz. github.com/JosiahBull/thinkpad_acpi/issues/13